# Recommended Intern directory structure for multiple package testing

Tags: javascript, dojo, amd, intern

I have gone thru the intern-tutorial which is a very simple unit test case. However, it's not clear to me if the directory structure can be different and how flexible intern's configuration can be to accommodate it.

I'd like to find a tutorial that showed the v1.1 intern locations **expected**... which locations are mandatory and which can be modified and how that impacts the config file (intern.js) settings. What is the directory structure intern expects for a project and what is changeable, such as when you have multiple packages even.

In particular I'd like to see the relative location relationships of the:

- web root
- intern dir
- intern.js config file
- unit-test files
- dojo/dijig/dojox/etc package location
- modules in a package

Please show how placement relates to the configuration settings if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of Intern 1.1, the only thing that is mandatory is that Intern be installed as an npm dependency of the root project being tested. There are no relationships to any of the things you asked about, except that everything needs to be within the project’s root directory.

Comment: By "root project" are you thinking of it as the "web root"? If we have multiple projects within a web root it seems it would be overkill to have to install an intern dir inside each project. Please clarify.

Comment: The web root needs to be inside the root project directory. It does not need to be the same directory.

Comment: But the intern dir still needs to be installed inside the web root to work. Right?

Comment: If you only ever use the test runner or Node.js client, no. Otherwise, yes.